# Making VSC MD preview collapsible

Tags: markdown, vscode-extensions

I am using markdown files in Visual Studio Code to document stuff I do.
Is there a way to collapse the different levels of content in the document?

i.e. I wish I could see just the lines that start with #
and then be able to toggle them and only see what's directly inside them
including ## with out the content of the "##".

I know that the Heading levels are not "containers"  and don't have closing tags,
but IMHO the semantics is there... so that if you have a line that begins with ### I would consider everything that follows it up to a line that begins with and equal or lesser amount of #'s to be its "content".
If necessary I would be willing to add /## lines at the end of each respective "opening" markdown segment. but as I said - I don't think it should be necessary.

I will be happy with any extension or built-in solution to help with this.

Comment: What do you mean by "preview"? What you're describing is syntax and doesn't match the title. And the answer is to actually use preview functionality. Unless you want preview with regular unformatted text, which is extremely niche and I don't see the purpose of it.

Comment: Have you reported this as a bug or request in the VS Code GitHub?

Comment: @Destroy666 I am not sure how to answer you. I have the .md text file and I have another window which displays a formatted version of the markdown (and this is what I reffered to as the preview.

Comment: @music2myear No I have not. I most certainly can't call it a bug. and I was trying to ask here in case what I am asking for / looking for could maybe be solved just by using some extension that I am not aware of. so no - no feature request either.

Comment: @epeleg so your description is quite inaccurate as it sounds that you want to collapse `#` etc. syntaxes that are not visible in preview. And which are collapsible normally. You should correct it to say you want to collapse specific sections of the document - space between headings, etc. This also seems rather niche and I doubt there's any extension.

Comment: @Destroy666 his description is perfectly fine, I have the same idea and i understand it immediately. This usage is not niche at all, in documentation platforms like Confluence and many docs websites, it is possible to collapse sections. A Preview of a Markdown file is a document so it is relevant.